# Зачем нужен null при скаффолдинге edit?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Зачем в стандартном скаффолдинге передаётся `int? id`?

```
// GET: MyEntity/Edit/5
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return this.NotFound();
    }

    var myEntity = await this._context.MyEntity.....

    if (myEntity == null)
    {
        return this.NotFound();
    }
    ...
}
```

Насколько я понимаю, можно совершенно спокойно поменять сигнатуру метода на int id. И главное - тут же для POST уже не проверяется:

```
// POST: MyEntity/Edit/5
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,")] MyEntity myEntity)
{
}
```

Или проектировщики из майкрософт что-то этим хотели дополнительно проверить?

Comment: Примеры взяты из core, но ЕМНИП и в классическом asp.net то же самое было.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что это сделано для того чтобы предотвратить загрузку формы редактирования при попытке перехода на нее через прямое редактирование строки адреса в браузере.