# От чего защищаемся когда id не id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Сижу читаю [статью с хабра](https://habr.com/en/company/jugru/blog/447308/), постепенно перенося код из презентации в тестовое приложение.

Добрался до следующего фрагмента, впал в ступор:

> Стало лучше? Стало! А еще мы теперь этот метод можем повторно
>   использовать в разных контроллерах. Результат налицо. Давайте
>   посмотрим на реализацию этого метода.

```
public void UpdateEmail(int id, string email)
{
    try
    {
        using (MiniProfiler.Current.Step("Update email"))
        {
            email = email.ToLower();
            var user = _userRepository.ById(id);
            if (user.Id != id)
            {
                var message = $"Попыткаизменитьчужиеданные {user.Id}/{id}";
                _logger.LogWarning(message);
                throw new SecurityException(message);
            }

            user.Email = email;
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException e)
    {
        _logger.LogCritical(e.Message);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Я что-то не особо понимаю, в чём смысл проверки `user.Id != id`, в каких случаях вообще возможна какая-то атака, что нужно отдельно предусмотреть данную проверку с выбросом SecurityException

На входе у нас int, не строка, значит навтыкать каких-то спецсимволов для эксплуатации sql injection не выйдет. В репозитории наверняка стоит тривиальное (см. код из предыдущих слайдов):

```
        var user = _dbContext.Set<User>()
                             .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
```

То есть мы ищем в базе x.Id == id и нам зачем-то приходит в голову тут же проверить, а вдруг они перестали быть равны.

Зачем??? Не понимаю, может кто понимает и объяснит?

Comment: Возможно, [это у майкрософт в скафолнинге CRUD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/811058/213987) тоже примерно для того же сделано?

Comment: @AlexKrass Это будет уже обычная проверка "нет такого пользователя", вполне типичная. А тут какая-то безопасность: пользователь существует, но "чужой". Я мог бы понять если была бы проверка user.OwnerId != id (где id = CurrentUserId), но тут явно какая-то логика, а не бред. Похоже, что автор что-то конкретное имеет ввиду, но что?

Comment: В содержимое не вникал, но там дальше в статье есть какой то `Id<T>`.

Comment: Еще возможно он защищается от самого себя. На пример если из-за ошибки `_userRepository.ById` вернет другого юзера.

Comment: @Vasek Гм, ну не исключено, например у нас объявлен интерфейс репозитория и мы можем подменять реализацию. Хотя вижу две натяжки: во-первых, автор статьи нигде ни словом не обмолвился, что нужны интерфейсы, у него может как раз жёстко гвоздями прибито, а во-вторых, ошибка безопасности -- это не ошибка кода, конфигурирования или чего-то ещё.

Comment: Я все равно склоняюсь к тому, что это бред или идея, которая не была до конца реализована и выглядит неуместно в конкретной ситуации. Мы запрашиваем из БД пользователя по Id и тут же проверяем, действительно ли нам БД вернула пользователя с таким Id. При этом запрос идет с внутренней стороны сервера и подменить его можно только в самом repository. Ладно, может кто ответит, самому интересно.

Comment: Если репозиторий возвращает по `id` юзера, у которого другой `id`, то это означает, что система работает неправильно. Возможно, автор таким образом пытается сказать: _Если `user.Id != id`, то система выдает что-то не то, и это небезопасно_. Единственное объяснение, которое я могу дать. Но это обычно проверяется тестами. Странный код, в общем.

Comment: Почему бы не спросить под статьей?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Спросил в ЛС, получил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Автор статьи ответил в личной переписке:

> В слайдах ошибка. Должно быть var user = _context.CurrentUser. Имеется
>   в виду проверка на то, что авторизованный пользователь пытается
>   изменить данные другого пользователя